# ZF2 empty output on underscore method

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translate

I've got an ZF2 application which is an extended skeletonapplication with a few extra modules like authentication and authorization, running on Zend Server comunity edition.

In order for poedit to find the strings it has to translate i use the _("string") method like so:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'eaddress',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'eaddress',
            'type' => 'email',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => _('EMAIL'),
        ),
    ));
```

But when I do that the application outputs nothing to the browser not even an error:

Firefox: The connection was reset

Chrome: No data received

Safari: {shows epmty page}

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there anything in your php/apache error_log? And did you verify that `function _($str)` is actually the cause for your problem? And lastly: where do you define the function?

Comment: No errors in the logs, When i only put 'label' => 'EMAIL', i get the expected result but without translation. The function lives in the __contruct method of the loginForm.

Comment: OK, that will be the error then ;) You can't construct functions inside of functions. Make a file `globalFunctions.php` and put this one into the `/public` folder. Include this one into your `index.php` and then it will all work.

Comment: Ok but what do i exactly put in the globalFunctions.php? And is it also possible to put this in the Module.php?

Comment: Yes it is, too, you put the functino declaration of `_($str)` in there

Comment: When I put _($str) in the application somewhere the application just stops with no errors or output.

Comment: You may have to learn a bit more about PHP i guess. `function _($str) { return $str; }`

Comment: I already tried that solution with no result. I don't think it has anything to do with my coding skills because the same code works on a other mac.

Comment: @Sam! i cant believe that recommendation of a global function coming from you! This is a ViewHelper issue, I agree that probably ViewHelpers will be too much for a newbie, but if so...ZF2 is also too much. Anyways, there is something that i dont understand, since as far as i know ZF2 actually works with poedit without writing any function. Ill try to explain a few things in an answer

Comment: @CarlosRobles you are wrong :) The issue here is not that of a ViewHelper. We already have the ViewHelper, which is `$this->translate()`. The issue here is only to allow POEdit to find hardcoded I18N-String inside classes, which is impossible without having a function wrapped around. For this we use a dummy function which does nothing but to return the string. A global function like this is absolutely accepted for the use-case ;)

Comment: @Sam sorry, i didn´t notice that you was talking about a dummy function. Anyways, poedit is already finding the translate function in the phtml files, and at any range i prefer to have poedit looking for actual functions doing actual stuff, rather than creating fake funtion for fulfilling administrative stuff. Anyways, i cannot give a reliable and irrefutable alternative in a not-too-broad answer, so i guess this is a good shortcut.

Comment: This solved the issue I was having:

[stackoverflow.com/a/21967903/909723][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21967903/909723

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you dont need to write any function in order to have ZF2 translating your literals. Actually it is working with poedit like a charm.

If you look at this [manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/styling-and-translations.html) you will see how to easily translate stuff in your views, just using `$this->translate()`, and there is where actually you have to do it.

About forms labels, you dont even have to worry since the form view helpers already translate label if everything is well configured.

If you want to know more about poedit and zf2 you can go to [this blog post](http://blog.hackix.com/2010/01/configuring-poedit-for-zend-framework-projects/) or this [great sams's post](http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/)