# PHP gettext method gives empty response

Tags: php, gettext, zend-server

When using the php gettext method like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
gettext("string");
//OR
_("string");
```

The server gives an empty response absolutely no output not even an error.
When commenting both methods out the page works like expected.

Firefox: The connection was reset

Chrome: No data received

Safari: {shows empty page}

I'm using: latest Zend Server locally on my Mac with OSX Mavericks (10.9.1).
Hope someone can help, I'm trying to fix this for about 2 weeks now and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be that on some systems setlocale() isn't enough.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

> Setting a language isn't enough for some systems and the putenv()
> should be used to define the current locale.

The issue was solved when I added:

```
putenv('LC_ALL=0');
```